# Passing parameters to shader with OpenFL

Tags: shader, haxe, openfl

I want to pass an array of vectors, or an array of float to a shader in OpenFL, is that possible?

Now I can only pass floats using something like this:

```
var param: ShaderParameter<Float> = new ShaderParameter<Float>();
param.value = [2.0];
this.data.some = param; // In the Shader class
```

But if I try with `Array<Float>` instead of `Float` it compiles but the values are not loaded to the shader.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really are supposed to pass arrays to shaders this way.
Have you tried setting the value directly through shader.data.param.value ?

Comment: Yes, but the values are not loaded to the shader

Answer (score 0):

Probably far too late for this answer, but did you try setting up the ShaderParameter before the super() call of the Shader's constructor? I had no luck getting custom parameters to work personally until I extended a Shader class (such as DisplayObjectShader), set up the params I wanted before super() inside, and then after the super() call doing everything else as normal (such as assigning whatever value to my parameter's "value" field). The underlying issue for me appeared to be timing-related, since the params wouldn't work if assigned after my Shader's parent constructor was executed.